# Plotting uneven row sizes in R

Tags: r, plot, row

I have data in tab delimited rows of uneven length and I want to make a histogram for each row:

```
1    23    352    4    12    94    0    2
434    13    29
5    93    93    34
(...more rows)
```

This is what I currently have (no fanciness included):

```
data = read.delim(file.txt,header = F, sep="\t")
for (j in 1:nrow(data)) { #loop over each row
    hist(data[j,])
```

But when I try to make the histogram, I think it tries to include the NA's in the row of the data frame, since R gives me the error message: "Error in hist.default(data[2, ]) : 'x' must be numeric".

When I try to use:

```
read.scan("file.txt, sep="\t")
```

I'm left with something I don't know how to separate by rows. Do I have a better option than splitting the file into one row per file and then reading in each row separately? (I am running into the same problem with uneven column size...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error results from the fact that grabbing a row from a data.frame yields an object of class `data.frame` (and `hist()` wants class `numeric`). Just convert it to `numeric`:

```
hist(as.numeric(data[j,]))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy to see there's a simple and understandable fix.